# Bulk Request failed in ElasticSinkConnector

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I got the following error while creating the elasticsinkconnector.

CREATE SOURCE CONNECTOR `testdemosinkconnector` WITH(
"type.name"= '_doc',
"input.data.format"= 'AVRO',
"connector.class"= 'io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector',
"tasks.max"= '1',
"transforms"= 'Dealership',
"topics"= 'es.contact.model',
"transforms.Dealership.type"= 'io.confluent.connect.transforms.ExtractTopic$Value',
"transforms.Dealership.field"= 'indexTopicName',
"transforms.Dealership.skip.missing.or.null"= 'true',
"connection.url"= 'https://elasticsearchdemo.es.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243',
"connection.username"= 'elastic',
"connection.password"= 'BUgBxOBg3dv4jp4Z3W7p4tHC',
"key.ignore"= 'true',
"value.converter"= 'io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter',
"value.converter.schemas.enable"= 'true',
"value.converter.schema.registry.url"= 'http://localhost:8081',
"bulk.size.bytes"= '-1',
"behavior.on.null.values"= 'IGNORE',`enter code here`
"behavior.on.malformed.documents"= 'IGNORE',
"max.retries"= '5',
"retry.backoff.ms"= '5000'
);

The error is,

```
FAILED | org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
                at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:618)
                at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:334)
                at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:235)
                at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:204)
                at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:200)
                at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:255)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
                at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
        Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Bulk request failed
                at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient$1.afterBulk(ElasticsearchClient.java:397)
                at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkRequestHandler$1.onFailure(BulkRequestHandler.java:70)
                at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener$5.onFailure(ActionListener.java:258)
                at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.Retry$RetryHandler.onFailure(Retry.java:126)
                at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.lambda$null$1(ElasticsearchClient.java:174)
                ... 5 more
        Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to execute bulk request due to 'java.io.IOException: Unable to parse response body for Response{requestLine=POST /_bulk?timeout=1m HTTP/1.1, host=https://elasticsearchdemo.es.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243, response=HTTP/1.1 200 OK}' after 6 attempt(s)
                at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.RetryUtil.callWithRetries(RetryUtil.java:165)
                at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.RetryUtil.callWithRetries(RetryUtil.java:119)
                at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.callWithRetries(ElasticsearchClient.java:425)
                at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.lambda$null$1(ElasticsearchClient.java:168)
                ... 5 more
        Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to parse response body for Response{requestLine=POST /_bulk?timeout=1m HTTP/1.1, host=https://elasticsearchdemo.es.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243, response=HTTP/1.1 200 OK}
                at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1632)
                at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1583)
                at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1553)
                at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.bulk(RestHighLevelClient.java:533)
                at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.lambda$null$0(ElasticsearchClient.java:170)
                at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.RetryUtil.callWithRetries(RetryUtil.java:158)
                ... 8 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:221)
                at org.elasticsearch.action.DocWriteResponse.<init>(DocWriteResponse.java:127)
                at org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse.<init>(IndexResponse.java:54)
                at org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse.<init>(IndexResponse.java:39)
                at org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse$Builder.build(IndexResponse.java:107)
                at org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse$Builder.build(IndexResponse.java:104)
                at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkItemResponse.fromXContent(BulkItemResponse.java:159)
                at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkResponse.fromXContent(BulkResponse.java:196)
                at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1892)
                at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.lambda$performRequestAndParseEntity$8(RestHighLevelClient.java:1554)
                at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1630)
                13 more
```

Please help me to resolve this error.
Elastic Sink Connector Version : 11.1.10
Elastic Search Version : 8.2.2

Answer (score 2):

Elasticsearch version 8 is not supported by the Confluent Elasticsearch Sink Connector Version 11.1.10 so most likely that it is why it can't parse the Elasticsearch response properly

> As of version 11.0.0, the connector uses the Elasticsearch High Level REST Client (version 7.0.1), which means only Elasticsearch 7.x is supported.

https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/current/overview.html